# What is the purpose of the new built in 'parse' validation key in Angular 1.3?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

The behavior of the ngModelController parsing pipeline seems to have changed between Angular 1.2 and 1.3.  I now always see a new validation key named `'parse'` added to all `$error` objects, and whenever one of the parsers returns undefined, it overrides/replaces all other validation keys that may have been already set.

For instance, here is a working example in Angular 1.2.23 - try entering a number out of range:

http://jsfiddle.net/8doq0saf/5/

The same thing running under 1.3-rc gives a different result:

http://jsfiddle.net/1t52s9b2/4/

I have not yet been able to find any documentation on this change. What is the purpose of the parse key, and how do I change my code to get back the old behavior?

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('number', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            // valid number
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                var valid = angular.isUndefined(value) || value === '' || isFinite(value);
                ctrl.$setValidity('number', valid);
                return valid
                    ? angular.isUndefined(value) || value === '' ? undefined : Number(value)
                    : undefined;
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                if (!angular.isDefined(attrs.minNumber)) {
                    return value;
                }
                var valid = angular.isUndefined(value) || Number(value) >= Number(attrs.minNumber);
                ctrl.$setValidity('minNumber', valid);
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                if (!angular.isDefined(attrs.maxNumber)) {
                    return value;
                }
                var valid = angular.isUndefined(value) || Number(value) <= Number(attrs.maxNumber);
                ctrl.$setValidity('maxNumber', valid);
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Angular 1.3 rationalized things to make a clean distinction between *parsing* and *validating*.

## Parsing

Angular now automatically adds a 'parse' key to all `$error` collections with its value set accordingly - `true` if any of the parsers returned `undefined`, `false` otherwise.

For an unparsable value (alphas entered for a number, badly formatted date, etc), we should return `undefined` from the parser. This will cause Angular to remove any `$error` keys already set, and replace the entire object with  just `{ "parse": true }`.  No more parsers will be run.  The model will not be updated.  The `$parsers` array should now only be used for parsing.

## Validation

[ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) has a new `$validators` property, to which we can assign validation functions.  These will only be run if the parsing pipeline was successful.  Return false from one of these functions for a value that is parsable as the required datatype, but merely invalid (string too long, number out of range etc).  The name of the validator function becomes the validation key in the `$error` object.  All validators will be run, even if one returns `false`.  The model will only be updated if validation is successful.

This is potentially a breaking change for existing applciations, as people frequently returned `undefined` from parsers for an invalid value. Here is what I had, which is a typical example:

```
ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
    if (!angular.isDefined(attrs.minNumber)) {
        return value;
    }
    var valid = angular.isUndefined(value) || Number(value) >= Number(attrs.minNumber);
    ctrl.$setValidity('minNumber', valid);
    return valid ? value : undefined;
});
```

Under this new scheme, this should be moved to a validation function instead:

```
ctrl.$validators.minNumber = function (value) {
    return !value || !angular.isDefined(attrs.minNumber) || (value >= Number(attrs.minNumber));
});
```

Here is the directive with everything fixed up:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('number', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            // valid number
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                if(value === '') return value;
                return isFinite(value) ? Number(value) : undefined;
            });

            ctrl.$validators.minNumber = function (value) {
                return !value || !angular.isDefined(attrs.minNumber) || (value >= Number(attrs.minNumber));
            };

            ctrl.$validators.maxNumber = function (value) {
                return !value || !angular.isDefined(attrs.maxNumber) || (value <= Number(attrs.maxNumber));
            };
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snkesLv4/10/

I really like this new way - it is much cleaner.

Comment: You should actually be using the new `$validators` pipeline for things such as your example. `ctrl.$validators.minNumber = function(val) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about this new feature.