# ngRequired and custom directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't seem to get the smart float directive found in the angular docs example working when used together with ngRequired.

You can confirm this by going to the angular docs page 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Edit the plunker on the smart float example, and add ng-required="false".
Make sure to check that the validity of the entire form, not the individual control.

The form itself is always marked as invalid if there is no input on the control.

I am using version 1.3.0-rc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow empty values for `smartFloat` directive you should use `$validators` for validity check of the float value in conjunction with `$parsers`. Also note that returning `undefined` (or not returning any value) from any of the parsers will mark the whole form is invalid.

**Allow empty values**

```
var FLOAT_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/;
app.directive('smartFloat', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      // Parse
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
        if (!viewValue) {
          return ''; // <-- Don't return undefined, but empty string instead
        } else if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          return parseFloat(viewValue.replace(',', '.'));
        }
      });
      // Validate
      ctrl.$validators.float = function (viewValue) {
          if (viewValue === '') {
            ctrl.$setValidity('float', true); // <-- Handle empty value as valid
            return true;
          } else if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('float', true);
            return true;
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('float', false);
            return false;
          }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Live example see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pLxOTaYNzaZL5DMdWwwi?p=preview).

Comment: I still can't get it to work. The problem is that the form itself is marked as invalid. The element itself doesn't seem to have any problems, but the form is marked as invalid if you do not have input on the directive.

Comment: @artbonghanoy Can you share the code (html + js)? Probably the issue is not with the directive itself.

Comment: @Vadmin, I finally figured it out. Please read this question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739986/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-new-built-in-parse-validation-key-in-angular-1-3). Please update your answer with the new validation scheme in 1.3 so I can accept it.

Comment: @artbonghanoy Thanks for pointing out the breaking change in validation flow. I've modified my answer accordingly.