# How to prevent model to be invalid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am a strong advocate of best practices, especially when it comes to angular but I can't manage to use the brand new `$validators` pipeline feature as it should be.

The case is quite simple: 1 input enhanced by a directive using `$parser`, `$formatter` and some `$validators`:

```
<input name="number" type="text" ng-model="number" number>
```

Here is the (simplified) directive:

```
myApp.directive('number', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    /*
     * Must have higher priority than ngModel directive to make
     * number (post)link function run after ngModel's one.
     * ngModel's priority is 1.
     */
    priority: 2,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
      $controller.$parsers.push(function (value) {
        return isFinite(value)? parseInt(value): undefined;
      });

      $controller.$formatters.push(function (value) {
        return value.toString() || '';
      });

      $controller.$validators.minNumber = function(value) {
        return value && value >= 1;
      };

      $controller.$validators.maxNumber = function(value) {
        return value && value <= 10;
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

**[I made a little plunk to play with :)](http://plnkr.co/edit/iUbUCfJYDesX6SNGsAcg?p=preview)**

The behavior I am trying to achieve is: **Considering that the initial value stored in the scope is valid, prevent it from being corrupted if the user input is invalid. Keep the old one until a new valid one is set.**

NB: Before angular 1.3, I was able to do this using `ngModelController` API directly in `$parser/$formatter`. I can still do that with 1.3, but that would not be "angular-way".

NB2: In my app I am not really using numbers, but [quantities](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities).The problem remains the same.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain I took my example's inspiration from your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25739987)

Comment: Tricky question... it looks like you want some parsing to happen after validation (setting the model to the last valid value rather than one derived from the view). However, I think the 1.3 pipeline works the other way around: parsing happens before validation. I'm not sure quite on your definition of best practice, but if you mean what is recommended/allowed by the docs, they say [in most cases it should be sufficient to use the ngModel.$validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setValidity), which leaves room for other cases, of which yours could be one.

Comment: @MichalCharemza What I would like is to keep my model always valid. And  the issue I have with the `$validators` is 1) If I write "42" in my input, the parser will return `42`, then the `maxNumber` validator will return `false` and set the model value to `undefined`. I would prefer keeping the last valid value in the model. 2) the `$validator` function receive 2 arguments when called internally by angular `modelValue, viewValue` and I have not found the way to identify the current validation: after parse or after formatting. In my real case, it matters :/

Comment: Yes, I think I understand your problem/question. My point is doing it just using the `$parser` pipeline, as you would in 1.2, is ok, because it's not possible (or at least, I haven't worked out how ;-) to use the `$validators` to achieve what you want.

Comment: @MichalCharemza About my 1st issue: I found that `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` prevents this unexpected behavior (but add more HTML...). About the 2nd issue: I can use a switch to determine the previous latest operation (parse or format).

Comment: Have you over simplified your example for the sake of a tidy question? Otherwise in this circumstance, why not just use a <select>?

Comment: @CodeMonkey I simplified the question for the sake of understanding first of all ;) I thought the reduced test case was difficult enough not to bring more complexity in this question. By `<select>' do you mean a unit select + a input for the scalar? As I said in other comments, for 1 input expecting a defined kind of quantity (volume, pressure) there are too many combinations possible of valid units * prefixes as you can see [here](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities/blob/master/src/quantities.js#L31). I don't think it would result to a good design for this control.

Comment: @CodeMonkey The initial goal of this directive (which is working currently, perfectible, but working) was to parse and format all these accepted quantities and their combinations. js-quantities is an incredible library to handle the scientific part. We are just looking for the best way to wrap it into an angular directive :)

Comment: @MichalCharemza If you want to add your comment I upvoted as a well detailed answer, I will accept it because you were the first (before @NewDev) to point out that the way `$validators` are currently implemented into angular, is just NOT designed to handle this use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want some parsing to happen after validation, setting the model to the last valid value rather than one derived from the view. However, I think the 1.3 pipeline works the other way around: parsing happens before validation.

So my answer is to just do it as you would do it in 1.2: using `$parsers`  to set the validation keys and to transform the user's input back to the most recent valid value.

The following directive does this, with an array of `validators` specified within the directive that are run in order. If any of the previous validators fails, then the later ones don't run: it assumes one validation error can happen at a time.

Most relevant to your question, is that it maintains the last valid value in the model, and only overwrites if there are no validation errors occur.

```
myApp.directive('number', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    /*
     * Must have higher priority than ngModel directive to make
     * number (post)link function run after ngModel's one.
     * ngModel's priority is 1.
     */
    priority: 2,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
      var lastValid;

      $controller.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        value = parseInt(value);
        lastValid = $controller.$modelValue;

        var skip = false;
        validators.forEach(function(validator) {
          var isValid = skip || validator.validatorFn(value);
          $controller.$setValidity(validator.key, isValid);
          skip = skip || !isValid;
        });
        if ($controller.$valid) {
          lastValid = value;
        }
        return lastValid;
      });

      $controller.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value.toString() || '';
      });

      var validators = [{
        key: 'isNumber',
        validatorFn: function(value) {
          return isFinite(value);
        }
      }, {
        key: 'minNumber',
        validatorFn: function(value) {
          return value >= 1;
        }
      }, {
        key: 'maxNumber',
        validatorFn: function(value) {
          return value <= 10;
        }
      }];
    }
  };
}]);
```

This can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/iUbUCfJYDesX6SNGsAcg?p=preview

Comment: As I promised, I accept this answer and delivers the reward that goes with it, congrats  :). I have ideas to improve it if it you do not mind ;) I am having some issues with plunkr right now but I'll try again later. Anyway, this code is very similar to our production's one but better organized. I do like this solution: it's clean, even if it is not "angular-way" since it does not seems possible for this use case. Thanks!

Comment: @glepretre Thanks! And with minutes to spare ;-). Feel free to edit it if there are some issues.

Comment: Haha yes, I woke up earlier to test your plunkr this morning! I like playing with deadlines :)

Comment: Not to be a sore loser, but how does this solve anything? You are essentially hard-coding validators into your own custom `number` directive? If that was @glepretre 's intent all along, you could have just directly set view or model values - there is not need to use neither parser nor validators. Put in other words, try setting another validator that invalidates when the number `3`, for example - and this approach completely fails.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are over-thinking this in terms of Angular-way vs. not Angular-way. Before 1.3 using `$parsers` pipeline was the Angular-way and now it's not?

Well, the Angular-way is also that `ng-model` sets the model to `undefined` (by default) for invalid values. Follow that Angular-way direction and define another variable to store the "lastValid" value:

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-maxlength="3" 
       ng-change="lastValidFoo = foo !== undefined ? foo : lastValidFoo"
       ng-init="foo = lastValidFoo">
```

No need for a special directive and it works across the board in a way that doesn't try to circumvent what Angular is doing natively - i.e. the Angular-way. :)

Comment: What I would like is to separate the concerns: in my (humble) opinion: `$parsers/$formatters` should return the correct `$modelValue/$viewValue` to set and the `$validators` should handle the CSS classes like `ng-valid/ng-invalid-[validator]` and the related ngFormController state `$valid/$invalid`. To avoid the `$validators` setting the model to `undefined` when returning `false`: I can add `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` to my HTML input tag.

Comment: @glepretre, `$validtors` do not "handle" CSS classes for valid/invalid - their sole purpose is to return true/false, and let `ngModel` to determine what that means. You can play tricks with `allowInvalid` and `getter/setter`, but it still doesn't get you far enough, and "by tricks" it seems to be going against the prized Angular-way

Comment: Ok, I simplified too much the process :D Of course the `$validators` do not handle directly the CSS classes but on their returning value depends the partial `setValidity(validationErrorKey, result)` and so on the related CSS class toggling `ng-valid-[key]/ng-invalid-[key]`. I agree with you about the tricks and the targeted angular-way. The initial objective of this question was to refactor and clarify our code, but I think even if there's a way to make it work, I'm afraid it would be uglier and longer than the old way so we won't merge it.

Answer (score 2):

As of Angular 1.3 you can use the ngModelOptions directive to have greater control as to when your model value updates. Take a look at this updated Plunker to show you how to achieve the functionality you are looking for: http://plnkr.co/edit/DoWbvlFMEtqF9gvJCjPF?p=preview

Basically you define the model as a getterSetter and only return the new value if it is valid:

```
 $scope.validNumber = function(value) {
  return angular.isDefined(value) ? ($scope.number = value) :  $scope.number;
}
$scope.modelOptions = {
  getterSetter: true,
  allowInvalid: false
};
```

Then to use this code update your  as follows:

```
 <input name="number" type="text" ng-model="validNumber" ng-model-options="modelOptions" number>
```

I really hope this answers all of your questions, please let me know if I can help any more.

Leon.

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving it a try ;) I have to say that's an interesting technique, but... the user experience becomes terrible :( Editing the input value is now rather difficult. As I said, the numbers between 1 & 10 is just the reduced use case, in our app we're parsing and formatting [quantities](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities) like `"1 m"`, `"12 ft"`, `"0.25 cm3"` and for example when validating a volume, `"0.25 cm"` is invalid until the user add the exponent `3`...

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you want to hear, but it sounds like you should rethink how you're doing the UI if it's going to be that confusing to an end user.  Give them a combo text input / drop-down control that lets them put in the numeric and select the type of quantity.  Your directive can control both, and now you've eliminated your confusion and made it easier to validate.

Comment: @Paul I'm afraid it's not that simple :) We are developing a scientific software and for 1 expected kind of quantity (let's take a pressure, for example), there are A LOT of possible units: Pascal, Bar, mmHg, torr, atm, psi... without forgetting the prefixes: milli, centi, deci, deca, hecto, kilo, mega... commonly used by the engineers who use our product ;)

Comment: @glepretre If you need to enter values such as "0.25 cm" then perhaps instead of a number input like I suggested you could use a text input and apply a regex using the ngPattern directive. Then it would work exactly like in my example but would also allow for any of the required formats - but still only apply to the model when valid. Does this sound something like what you would want?

Comment: The regExp pattern won't be easy to determine :/ And the original goal of the directive was to wrap all this complex validation process into a generic one using the quantities objects because they expose all we need to validate (scalar, unit, unit signature, original value...).

Comment: You can still wrap all the complexity into a directive but you will need to know the rules to what makes the field valid. Once you have a way of correctly validating the field you can use the above example to then ensure the model is only updated once valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HfYn6fBRsNKRp79HGWXK?p=preview) with the relevant code:

```
$controller.$$runValidators = function(originalRun) {
        var lastModelValue, lastViewValue;
        return function() {
          var ctrl = this;
          var doneCallback = arguments[arguments.length-1];
          arguments[arguments.length-1] = function(allValid) {
              doneCallback(allValid);
              console.log(allValid);
              console.log('valid:' +allValid+ ' value:' +ctrl.$viewValue);
              if (ctrl.$viewValue) {
                lastViewValue= allValid ? ctrl.$viewValue : lastViewValue | '';
                lastModelValue= allValid ? ctrl.$modelValue : lastModelValue;
                ctrl.$modelValue = allValid ? ctrl.$modelValue : lastModelValue;
                ctrl.$$writeModelToScope();
                ctrl.$viewValue = ctrl.$$lastCommittedViewValue = lastViewValue;
                ctrl.$render();

              }
              console.log(ctrl.$viewValue + '  '+lastViewValue);

             // console.log( ctrl.$modelValue);
          };
          originalRun.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      }($controller.$$runValidators);
```

Can it be a valid solution?
the only way i think you can intercept the angular validation flow is override the $$runValidators. Maybe this code need a little bit of tweaking but works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I have to say I did not expect such creativity when I asked my question :) Unfortunately I see 2 issues with this solution: 1) the user experience seems weird as the input value is overwritten, preventing the user to write what it wants to immediately (same issue as @LeonRevill answer). This is too frustrating I think. 2) I like the way you overrode the `$$runValidators` function but I'm afraid it would be too risky to test and maintain this solution when upgrading to a newer stable version of angular ;)

Comment: @glpretre Thanks for your appreciations, i was unsure, after i posted the answer, it was too far from your requirements (especially for the point 'the angular way'). Digging in the angular code I didnt find an appropriate method for what you need, anyway i enjoyed the try. Good luck!