# AngularJS input type number doesn't update the model when typing letters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

Apparently some browsers allow users to type letters in a numeric input field  (e.g. Chrome  46.0.2490.80 on mac or Chrome  41.0.2272.89 on Ubuntu). Furthermore, all the browser accept the character 'e' as in some particular conditions it can be considered a valid number.

Now, apparently Angular fails to update the model if the user intorduces any letters in that field.

You can see that in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Jg6/78/

```
<h1>Simple Data Binding with AngularJS</h1>
<br />
<div ng-app>
Name: <input type="number" ng-model="name" />
<br /><br />
   Welcome to AngularJS {{name}}
</div>
```

Is this the expected behavior? In this way there are moments in which the model is not reflecting the value of the input field and that can lead to unexpected errors (I'm thinking about field validation for example)

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting a number, then any letters in that field would make the model value invalid (unless of course it is the 'e' that you mention). Angular 1.4.x uses this regex to determine if the number is allowed or not:

```
var NUMBER_REGEXP = /^\s*(\-|\+)?(\d+|(\d*(\.\d*)))([eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*$/;
```

As you can see, the 'e' or 'E' is valid in this case (but no other letters are). Your jsfiddle uses an older version of angular where the 'e' char seems to not be correctly parsed and therefore makes the model invalid. Here is the same [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da1g0j7y/) using Angular 1.4.7 where it parses the number correctly (those containing e or E).

Your app would presumably use validation to determine that the model is populated if it is in fact a required field. If you truly want to allow non-numeric in your model, consider a different "type" on the input.

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected, only when the input data is valid the model is updated

You might be able to override this behaviour with ngModelOptions : {allowInvalid: true} (does not work for input type=number afaik)

docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Also see this question: 
[How can I override Angular's filtering of invalid form values, forcing Angular to persist the $viewValue to $modelValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345987/how-can-i-override-angulars-filtering-of-invalid-form-values-forcing-angular-t)